# Where can I see folk music and dancing in Moldova?

Tags: online-resources, events, music, moldova

We'll be taking a holiday in Moldova and are interested in watching a performance of Moldovan folk music and dancing.  There are evidently large and elaborate productions by groups such as the [Flueras National Folk Dance Ensemble](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWe9SiuqagI), though I imagine there must also be some smaller-scale ensembles who perform at various venues and festivals.

Is there anywhere in (or easily reachable from) Chișinău that we could see such a performance?

Perhaps websites that list upcoming performances throughout the country?

Answer (score 4):

Your only shot at seeing a dance recital would be in Chisinau.
I'd doubt they're organized enough to advertise an upcoming show online. I think your best bet is to investigate when you're there.

Cahul may have something as well, just because of the university. But, your best chance is walking around Chisinau or asking at your hotel.